# How can i get result returned by calling @@IDENTITY through sqlsrv extension?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv

I have some SP (stored procedure) like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_INSERT_ELEMENTS]
@IN_OWNER_CLASS_ID  int
AS
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ELEMENTS] (OWNER_CLASS_ID)  VALUES (@IN_OWNER_CLASS_ID)
RETURN @@IDENTITY
```

And some PHP function, to call this SP:

```
function createEmptyElement($class){
$conn = l_connection::db_connect();
$proc_query = '{ call PROC_INSERT_ELEMENTS ( @IN_OWNER_CLASS_ID=? ) }';
$params = array(
array(&$class->ID, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
       );
$resource=sqlsrv_query($conn, $proc_query, $params);
sqlsrv_next_result($resource);
sqlsrv_fetch($resource);
var_dump(sqlsrv_get_field($resource, 0));
```

I want to get `ID` of new created row at `ELEMENTS` table, but i can't do this, because `@@IDENTITY` doesn't return row (i think).

Oh, and i can't change SP.

Comment: What `var_dump` shows?

Comment: it shows `bool(false)`